# How to pass report parameters from one report to another report in Birt

Tags: birt

I am very new to the Birt Tool, and would need to find out how to pass report parameters from one report to another. In this particular case, I want to pass "from date" and "to date" parameters.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a hyperlink on the field or chart element that you want to make click-able as a drill through to the secondary report.  From there you can set the Hyperlink to be of type "drill through" and set any parameters using data on the currently available data set or some static value.  The parameters supported by the target report will automatically be read in when you configure the Hyperlink's properties.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi MystikSpiral Please could you give answer for this question in link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486420/birt-report-passing-multiple-value-from-one-report-to-another-on-spago-bi-serve